# How to record audio and write audio data to file in android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I want to record audio and write audio data to file in android.

I have to use these parameters this function for recording audio.

```
AudioRecord: AudioSource:VOICE_COMMUNICATION, sampleRate : 48000 ChannelConfiguration : channel_in_mono, PCM_16bit.
buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(960);
audioRecord.read(ByteBuffer buffer, int capacity);
```

And then I have to write audio data to write file and then play it by using AudioTrack.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice tutorial on Android Developers webpage.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

When creating MediaRecorder object, you can set sampling rate to it by doing this:
`mediarecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(int x)`

Im pretty sure you can set the other parameters too, just follow the link above and its sub-links.

I dont know if this is your desired way of solving your problem, hopefully it will lead you to the right track. Good luck!